# maven deploy-file to private artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I've set up an artifactory and I am able to to deploy my artifacts to it with `mvn deploy`.

However, I am unable to to `deploy-file`, which I am easily able to install:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=my.jar -DgroupId=org.group -DartifactId=art -Dversion=3.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

When I try:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://myartifactory/artifactory/repositoryId -DrepositoryId=repositoryId -Dfile=my.jar -DgroupId=org.group -DartifactId=art -Dversion=3.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

I always get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to retrieve remote metadata org.directwebremoting:dwr:3.0.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata org.directwebremoting:dwr:3.0.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to repository (http://triphop:8081/artifactory/repository): Access denied to: http://triphop:8081/artifactory/repository/org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml -> [Help 1]
```

In the log of the artifactory I am getting:

```
20130809142431|0|REQUEST|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repository/org/group/art/3.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|401|0
```

Why the maven is trying to fetch the meta data? Why it does not upload them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven 3 works with non unique snapshots only. Which means, it needs to know how to name your snapshot. The naming depends on what's already in repository. That's the reason it downloads the metadata.

Comment: Allow anonymous reads or configure sever credentials for Artifactory in settings.xml